# processing.video: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library: gstreamer

Tags: java, processing, libraries

I'm trying to use the `processing.video` library for my VS Code project in linux. I imported the library, and there were no errors, but when I setup basic code to just load a `.mp4` file and play it, I got an error saying:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library: gstreamer

Could someone tell me why this is happening, and what I need to do to fix this? I was unaware that I needed to install other dependencies and I didn't see others having this problem.

Comment: which version of Processing are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

First, run a quick program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(Sytem.getProperty("java.library.path");
}
```

Once you have that information, make sure that the gstreamer .dll is in that location.

Alternatively, set the path argument to the location of the gstreamer .dll using the command line "java a.b.myclass" argument